# Fit text in face of folding polyhedron with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, text-decorations

After a good amount of trial and error, I have managed to fit the text I wanted to face 1 of this polyhedron:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary {folding}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
  \pic [
    folding line length=6mm,
    transform shape,
    face 1= { \node[text width=2.9cm,text height=11pt,scale=0.2,inner sep=10pt] {

        {\bf Cayendo en las redes de Venecia}\\
        ~\\
        JJ Merelo};
    },
    face 2= { \node{ Tibi }; },
    face 3= { \node{\tiny Marce}; },
    face 4= { \node{\tiny Evangelista}; },
    face 5= { \node{\tiny Meus}; },
    face 6= {  \node[anchor=center] {\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{dogos} };}
  ]
  { cube folding };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in this:

[image: Badly shaped cube]

Minimal incremental improvement from here would be to avoid text so close to folding edges, but `inner sep` does not seem to work right. However, what I would like is to have some idiomatic way of actually fitting text to the corresponding face. Right now, I have to tweak 3 different parameters: `text width`, `text height` and `scale`. Would there be a single command that fits the node to the shape, or a single "scale" that can be used to fit? Would the node width, for instance, be stored in a variable like `\textheight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some keys to play with:

- `scale text = {<text>}{<width>}` scales the node so that a single (!) line and the `inner xsep` fits the given width. The `min` function makes sure that the text doesn't get scaled when it fit on its own. The `\tiny` needs to be moved outside of the node so that it functions more properly.
- `scale text width = {<scale>}{<width>}` sets the text width and scales the node so that the `<width>` is the total width of the node when it gets scaled. Once again, the `inner xsep` is included.

In both cases, the `inner xsep` value can be used to change the padding.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {folding}
\tikzset{
  scale text width/.style 2 args={
    text width={(#2-2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}))/(#1)},
    scale={#1}},
  scale text/.style 2 args={
    node contents={#1},
    scale={min(1,(#2)/(width("{#1}")+2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=10]
  \pic [
    folding line length=6mm,
    transform shape,
    inner sep=+.15em,
    face 1= { \node[scale text width={.2}{6mm}] {
        \textbf{Cayendo en las redes de Venecia}\\[1.3em]JJ Merelo}; },
    face 2= { \node[scale text={Tibi}{6mm}]; },
    face 3= { \tiny \node[scale text={Marce}{6mm}]; },
    face 4= { \tiny \node[scale text={Evangelista}{6mm}]; },
    face 5= { \tiny \node[scale text={Meus}{6mm}]; },
    face 6= { \node{\includegraphics[width=0.6cm]{example-image} };}
  ]
  { cube folding };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: So if got this right, you're defining two functions with two arguments each, but essentially you're playing with `\pgfkeysvalueof` to get the length of the text, is that correct?

Comment: @jjmerelo Not quite. `\pgfkeysvalueof` is used to get the value of [`inner xsep`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#pgf/inner:xsep). The text is `#1` with `scale text` and it is measured by the `width` function of PGFMath. With `scale text width` I'll set the width to the given width `#2` after scaling.